# How do I track a form submission in tag manager when it has the same div class as the error message?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I was making an element visibility tag to track when my form shows the thank you message. Typically I use a CSS selector. However, the CSS selector is the same for both the error message and the success message.

Error:

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true">One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.</div>
```

Success:

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true">Thank you for your message. It has been sent.</div>
```

Comment: You're supposed to use context. The parent elements. Show us more HTML. Like, the whole context of both messages if you want the actual CSS selector that would differentiate between them from us.

Answer (score 1):

In a visibility trigger, the built-in `{{Click Text}}` variable assumes the value of the innerText property of the selected element.

So if you select the element via `css selector equals .wpcf7-response-output`, you can then apply a filter `Click Text starts with Thank you` to recognize the success message.

Not the most robust solution, and takes extra steps on multilingual pages, but if you do not change the text of your success message too often it should work.